# Problems with the TDAPIOLELib library

Tags: c#, visual-studio, alm, hp-quality-center, hp-alm

I am trying to build a C# program with Visual Studio to use the ALM OTA API. I keep on having problems with the TDAPIOLELib library though, and I can't seem to find the reason why. I get the following error:

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: clrhost): Loaded 'c:\users\[...]\source\repos\ALM API 2\ALM API 2\bin\Debug\netcoreapp2.0\Interop.TDAPIOLELib.dll'. Module was built without symbols.
An unhandled exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Unknown Module.
Method not found: 'TDAPIOLELib.TDConnection
```

I installed the "HP ALM Connectivity" and I did the "Register HP ALM" and the "Register HP ALM Site Administration".

In my project, I have a reference to the OTAClient.dll and Interop.TDAPIOLELib.dll withing the Debug folder, so that should be fine... Perhaps is it related to the "Module was built without symbols." part?

I also read somewhere that it could be related to the fact that the library is 32bit, so I change the Debug to x86, but then "dotnet has stopped working" and I get the following:

```
'dotnet.exe' (CoreCLR: DefaultDomain): Loaded 'C:\Program Files\dotnet\shared\Microsoft.NETCore.App\2.0.6\System.Private.CoreLib.dll'. Symbols loaded.
The program '[18248] dotnet.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[18248] dotnet.exe' has exited with code -532462766 (0xe0434352).
```

Any idea on what I am missing?

Thanks.

Comment: This is a COM interop assembly.  Somehow it is running with a different version of the assembly than the one it was compiled with.  Use Fuslogvw.exe and log all binds to have some idea where it came from.  A bad version in the GAC would not be an uncommon accident.  Do note that using .NETCore tooling is not advisable, any machine that has this COM component also has the full version of the .NET Framework available.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I feel like I don't have the necessary experience with these specifics, so please bear with me.

I have to run Fuslogvw.exe, "Log all binds to disk" and share the contents of the created log?

Regarding the .NETCore tooling, would you know how to not use it?

From what I understand of your answer, would it help if I just created a new project and compile it again?

Comment: (I hope this is what you mean). The following is the log I get from interop.OTAClient, Version=12.1.9999.0:

https://pastebin.com/vKYqBaZP

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved the problem. It looks like .NET Core was not only not advisable but just wrong. I was using a .NET Core project, but the OTAClient.dll is assembled for .NET Framework 4.0. I created a Framework project and it worked.

Anyways, thanks for your help, @Hans Passant